# calculating the top-right offset of div while rotating it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculate the top-right position of div , i can calculate it, if it is not rotated with:

```
  $("div").offset().top + $("div").width();
```

But when we rotate `div` then , how we can calculte top-right position ?

Rotate code:

```
$("div").slider({ 
   slide: function(e,u){ 
      $(this).rotate({ angle : u.value});  
   }
});
```

Comment: How are you rotating it?

Comment: Show that code as well please.

Comment: $("div").slider({ slide: function(e,u){ $(this).rotate({angle:u.value});}});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

**JavaScript**

```
$(".slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 180,
   slide: function(e,u){ 
      $(this).rotate({ angle : u.value});
       calculateTopLeft(u.value);
   }
});

var pointer = $('.pointer');
var slider = $('.slider');
var center = { top: slider.offset().top, left: slider.offset().left + slider.width() / 2 };
var offset = slider.offset();

function calculateTopLeft(angle) {
    var radius = slider.width() / 2,
        radians = (angle * Math.PI) / 180;
    pointer.css({
        left: center.left + radius * Math.cos(radians),
        top: center.top + radius * Math.sin(radians)
    });
}
//Equation of the circle
//x = a + r * cos(t);
//y = b + r * sin(t);​
```

And here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/zFRwM/2/

Probably you'll need a little correction but I think that the idea is clear.

Answer (score 1):

use this in your javascript

```
function getPosition(obj){
    var topValue= 0,leftValue= 0;
    while(obj){
    leftValue+= obj.offsetLeft;
    topValue+= obj.offsetTop;
    obj= obj.offsetParent;
    }
    finalvalue = leftValue + "," + topValue;
    return finalvalue;

}

var d = document.getElementById('divname');
getPosition(d);
```

Then try this,it use  .position() function in jquery use this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
var p = $("div");
var position = p.position();
$("div").text( "Right: " + position.right + ", top: " + position.top );
</script>
```

Comment: Not working showing the same offset after rotation but thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Remove transform, retrieve offset, put transform back:

```
$.fn.offsetNoTransform = function(e)
{
    var m = this.css('transform');
    this.css('transform', '');
    var off = this.offset();
    this.css('transform', m);
    return off;
}
```